# R infer package generate() function error

Tags: r, inference

I am working with the infer package in R. I am attempting to create permutations of the data using the generate() function and store the results into a tibble called homeown_perm. The data is simply two columns of Gender (male or female) and HomeOwn (Own or Rent). The data comes from the R dataset NHANES. I get an error when trying to use the generate() function that I do not understand. In fact this code works perfectly fine while I use it in an excercise on DataCamp but not on my own R studio session. This is the error:

Error in vctrs::vec_chop(seq_len(n * reps), sizes = rep(n, reps)) :
unused argument (sizes = rep(n, reps))

And this is the code that anyone should be able to try to run:

```
# Load packages
library(infer)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(NHANES)

homes <- NHANES %>%
  # Select Gender and HomeOwn
  select(Gender, HomeOwn) %>%
  # Filter for HomeOwn equal to "Own" or "Rent"
  filter(HomeOwn %in% c("Own", "Rent"))


# Perform 10 permutations
homeown_perm <- homes %>%
  specify(HomeOwn ~ Gender, success = "Own") %>%
  hypothesize(null = "independence") %>% 
  generate(reps = 10, type = "permute")
```

I have tried simplifying the code by using fewer reps, removing the arguments in generate, changing homes variable to a tibble and data frame. I am expecting the code to return homeown_perm, a tibble with 3 columns and 97,120 rows. The columns should be HomeOwn, Gender and replicate. It should be essentially re-samples (permutations) of the original homes data.

Comment: I just installed NHANES and I get no error.got a tibble with `# A tibble: 97,120 × 3
# Groups:   replicate [10]`. Voting to close as not reproducible. To continue the discussion it would be useful to know all details about versions of installation including OS, IDE, R, packages.